# Twitter API 1.1: Return all tweets that contain a certain hashtag OR are by a specific user

Tags: twitter

Is there an API call which will return all the tweets which contain an specific hashtag (#example) and also all the tweets from a certain user (@example)?

Looking for a single API call, that returns a JSON object with both those criteria.
I know I can do with two separate API calls, but I an trying to do this with one.  Possibly https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets is the best bet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use multiple terms together, Twitter search performs an AND operation by default. i.e.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets.json?q=from%3AJoeMayo%20%23twitterapi

Returns only tweets that are from JoeMayo and contain #twitterapi.

You can experiment with it on Twitter's [Search](https://twitter.com/search/#) page.

Comment: Thanks: I did and came up with q=from%3Aexample%20OR%20%23example+exclude:retweets and it works

Comment: If I don't have a restriction on the username and want all tweets with the hashtag, will it return tweets that're year old or at least month old unlike REST API.

Comment: @CuriousVoraciousBushie Your results are limited. At https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets, Twitter states that their search API is not an exhaustive search. At https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search they indicate that their index goes back 6 to 9 days. I've seen the days vary and their search web site at https://twitter.com/search-home is more accurate than their REST API.

Comment: True that.. I've got another source that has streamed the data for the last 8 months. So, I don't have a better option than that. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=shrmi14

is the one that i used.

Incase you feel issues. refer https://dev.twitter.com/console for generating your own queries..